# How to calculate a sumatory of a series?

Tags: r, for-loop, series

I'm trying to calculate the sumatory of a series and I don't know what is my mistake because I don't get the right result.  The sumatory that I have to calculate is this

[image]

Here, Z(n,i) is a numeric vector ordered from the samllest to the greatest.

What I have done is this

```
wi<-c()
wi[1]=1/(1/n^2) #n is n<-length(Z) where Z is the numeric vector of data
for(i in 1:n){
   for(j in 2:i){
       wi[i]=w[i-1]+1/(1(n-j+1)^2)
   }
}
```

Is there another way to set this sum without calculating the first term before the for loop?
Is this sum correctly defined?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how about `1/cumsum(lapply(1:length(Z), function(i){1/(length(Z) - i + 1)}))`

Comment: Hi, gfgm.  Thanks for your solution.  It worked perfectly!!!!! Could you post it like an answer in  order to qualify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can compactly calculate the sumatory like so:

```
1/cumsum(lapply(1:length(Z), function(i){1/(length(Z) - i + 1)}))
```